# jTDS JDBC not throwing exception when it should

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have a problem with the following code using the jTDS JDBC Driver. Everything works, and queries is no problem. But I don`t get an error/exception if the connection is failing. I have tried to enter a false IP, disable local network connection, provide false port number etc., but no luck. I really need to know when the connection fails.

It seems that everything stops at the line: "con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);" (But only when it really should throw an exception...)

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {


    java.sql.Connection con = null;


    String url= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x/DATABASE";
    String id= "seret";
    String pass = "secret";

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");


    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

    con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);

    System.out.println("Connected?")
    //Program never gets here, but does not close either.

    if(con.isValid(1000)) System.out.println("Does not work either...");

    if(con!=null) con.close();      

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't get an exception.  I do get a SQLException (SQLState=S1000) when using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2000 with jTDS 1.2.4.

If upgrading your jTDS driver doesn't help you might try appending ";loginTimeout=20" to your URL string.  So it would look like:

```
String url= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x/DATABASE;loginTimeout=20";
```

Then rerun your application and wait at least 20 seconds.  Hopefully you will get a timeout exception.

If the loginTimeout setting didn't help you can also play with the socketTimeout setting.  Although see the jTDS FAQ concerning the implications of using socketTimeout.  Basically you want to set it longer than the longest query you expect your application to execute.